# XG MIDI File Format

Tags: midi

I have a Yamaha MIDI guitar, that, when I play a MIDI file encoded using the XG MIDI standard, causes certain lights on the guitar to turn on and off. I am trying to determine the MIDI event that causes this so that I can programmatically send the same event without the use of a MIDI file (the same way I can send a Note On (144) or Note Off (128) command).

However, while I have been able to locate a copy of the MIDI protocol, I have not been able to locate the XG MIDI protocol. Is there a way, beyond trying to send all possible commands to the device until I locate the appropriate command, to determine what the MIDI event is that is causing the lights to change state? Or is there somewhere that I can get a copy of the XG MIDI protocol?

Comment: This question is not programming related and doesn't belong to SO.
I recommend reading a manual of your instrument.

Comment: That is not correct. I am talking about automating the sending of such information, which would be a programming question.

Answer (score 4):

The Yamaha manuals for their products detail the information you are looking for. The XG commands are device specific. Some XG commands give direct access to the device memory and my manual for the MU2000 tone generator warns that "you can damage the unit by sending incorrect data"

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

1. XG is the semantic extension of MIDI protocol. It doesn't change anything in the structure of the MIDI file. The only thing is, that if you use an XG-compatible instrument to record, say, changes of the resonance of the filter, it will cause the same effect on any other XG instrument. But on the MIDI procotol level, you will still have the CC (Control Change) message #71 (IIRC).
2. MIDI protocol is very extensible and leaves a lot of space for manufacturers. Not only you can use CC messages, but also Registered Parameter Numbers (RPNs) and NRPNs (Non-Registered ones). On top of it you have System Exclusive (SysEx) messages and I would bet that an appropriately crafted SysEx message could change the lights on the guitar. Try to get so-called "Data List" for your instrument, it should include all the information about the MIDI messages that are being sent/received by your guitar.

Answer (score 3):

*Wikipedia*: "In 1999, the official GM [[General MIDI]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI) standard was updated to include more controllers, patches, RPNs and SysEx messages, in an attempt to reconcile the conflicting and proprietary Roland GS and Yamaha XG additions." This was called [General MIDI 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_MIDI_Level_2).

I recommend looking into what Java ([javax.sound.midi](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/package-summary.html)) has to offer (C# seems to be lacking a solid MIDI library). Read up on [MetaMessage](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/MetaMessage.html), [ShortMessage](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/ShortMessage.html), [SysexMessage](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/SysexMessage.html), and [Patch](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/Patch.html). From what I understand, special system messages are sent through SysexMessage (the lighting data might be here).

If you need some sample code look at [Java Sound Resources](http://www.jsresources.org/examples/).

Other links I found:

- [Working with XG SYSEX on the Yamaha QY70](http://www.ksanti.net/qy70/index.html)
- [Win32API::MIDI::SysEX::Yamaha](http://search.cpan.org/~hayashi/Win32API-MIDI-0.05/MIDI/SysEX/Yamaha.pm)

Answer (score 1):

For a managed .NET Midi Library look for the C# Midi Toolkit on codeproject.com.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the codeproject midi toolkit by Leslie Sanford to communicate with the guitar.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MIDIToolkit.aspx

Everything you need to know about the guitars communications is in the manual on a single page near the back.

Here is a video of an editor I built - it features full communications with the guitar.

[YouTube Video of Guitar Program](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UYJI1MhPbo)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you'll need to find that information from the manufacturer.  It's likely a sysex message, although it could also be a controller.

Walking through all the controllers is pretty simple in software so you could try that if you wanted.  But the chances of stumbling upon the right sysex message by accident or exhaustive search is close to astronomical.

Dig through the back of your manuals.  It might be in there.  If not, google for the sysex for your device.  Otherwise you'll need to ask Yamaha for the info.